# How can I transfer data from my PS4 to my PS4 Pro without using the cloud?

Tags: ps4

I bought a PS4 Pro and I was wondering what the easiest way to transfer my data from my PS4 to the PS4 Pro without uploading it to online storage is? I don't have unlimited downloading, so uploading all my games to the cloud from the PS4 and then downloading to the PS4 Pro would be too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, there appears to be a very easy way to do this *without* using the cloud services! From [the official Playstation blog](https://blog.eu.playstation.com/2016/11/09/how-to-transfer-your-data-from-ps4-to-ps4-pro/):

> **1. Check your system software is version 4.0 or higher**
>
> First, make sure both your existing PS4 and your PS4 Pro have been updated to the latest system software. This should have happened on your existing PS4 automatically, last time you went online – but if you’re not sure, go to “Settings” and scroll down to “System Software Update”.
>
> **2. Connect to your broadband network and sign in to PSN**
>
> You’ll need to switch on both PS4 consoles and ensure they both connect to your home broadband network – either via Wi-Fi or with LAN cables – so you can sign in to PlayStation Network.
>
> For the data transfer, only your new PS4 Pro will need to be connected to your TV. Sign in to the new console with your PSN ID and password to get started.
>
> **3. Prepare your data**
>
> Once that’s done, your PS4 Pro will detect that you’re signing in to a new console with your PSN ID and you’ll see a screen asking if you want to start transferring data from your old console to your shiny new one.
>
> Follow the on-screen prompt to confirm you want to start the transfer process, then press and hold the Power button on your old console (until you hear a beep) to prepare your data.
>
> **4. Connect both consoles with a LAN cable**
>
> Next, connect the two PS4s together with a LAN cable, into their respective LAN ports on the back of the console.
>
> Alternatively, you can connect each PS4 to your router, using two LAN cables. The transfer process will be exactly the same.
>
> **5. Choose the data you want to transfer**
>
> You’ll have a choice of what data you want to transfer; you can pick which applications or games are moved across (or just copy all of them), as well as your game save data, screenshots and videos you’ve captured, themes and settings.
>
> Once you’ve chosen what data is going to be moved across, you’ll be shown how much free space will be left on the new console’s hard drive once the process is complete, and an estimate of how long the transfer will take.
>
> **6. Activate your primary PS4**
>
> Finally, you’ll be asked if you want to activate your new console as your primary PS4. This will allow you to automatically download updates, upload save game data to your PS Plus cloud storage and share content with other users.

It looks like doing all of these steps will transfer all game and save data, but will not transfer passwords or unregistered profiles or unsynched trophy data, so be sure to sync your trophies before you do the transfer!

Another important thing to note from that guide:

> If you’ve started using your new console before you begin a full data transfer onto it, anything you’ve saved to the hard drive will be wiped.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you have overlapping SSIDs for your 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks the migration will complain that it can't "see" any other PS4s as the pro will connect to 5GHz and the regular will be on 2.4GHz.  Where the documentation says "home broadband network" it really means "same network, protocol, and band".  You may have to change the SSID of one of your networks temporarily or disable 5GHz until you initiate the migration.

Comment: thx Venomous and Foosh. great info.

Comment: Also, connecting and transferring over the Ethernet cable took me about 6 hours but I had 3/4 of the storage space on my 500GB PS4 used, no photos or videos - just game data and save files.